# Formatting grep output in command line

Tags: linux, grep, formatting

I used this following grep command to search a text in a multiple files.

```
grep -w 'mytext' *.txt
```

now my result is,

```
a.txt:mytext          32.15        
b.txt:mytext          27.65        
c.txt:mytext          37.95
```

Its like

```
{filename}.{extension}:{searched-line}
```

But I want this result like formatted below:

```
{filename}:{searched-line}
```

Just I don't want the extension of that files. How can I do that in command line?

Comment: do you mind remove it with sed command?

Comment: But I heard that grep is faster that sed. Just I think.

Comment: how can you have `a.txt:mytext          32.15`  when your command runs on `*.pri`?

Comment: also how do you want to treat files with extensions like `.tar.gz`?

Comment: @Allan: sorry. I just corrected now. Please now see it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment, you can just pipe it to `sed` command:

```
$ echo -e "a.txt:mytext 32.15\nb.tar.txt:mytext 34.15" | sed 's/\.[^:]*:/:/g'
a:mytext 32.15
b:mytext 34.15


$ echo -e "a.txt:mytext 32.15\nb.tar.txt:mytext 34.15" | sed 's/\.[^.:]*:/:/g'
a:mytext 32.15
b.tar:mytext 34.15
```

depending on if you want to keep the sub-extension or not.

```
grep -w 'mytext' *.txt | sed 's/\.[^:]*:/:/g'
```

or

```
grep -w 'mytext' *.txt | sed 's/\.[^.:]*:/:/g'
```

depending on what you want to achieve.

with `awk` you can achieve the same:

```
$echo -e "a.txt:mytext 32.15\nb.tar.txt:mytext 34.15" | awk -F'\\.[^:]*:' 'BEGIN{OFS=":"}{print $1,$2}'
a:mytext 32.15
b:mytext 34.15
```

or

```
$echo -e "a.txt:mytext 32.15\nb.tar.txt:mytext 34.15" | awk -F'\\.[^.:]*:' 'BEGIN{OFS=":"}{print $1,$2}'                                      
a:mytext 32.15
b.tar:mytext 34.15
```